# Use Sock5 Proxy in VBA

Tags: vba, proxy, msxml, socks

I want to route all the web traffic generated by the Excel VBA tool through a Sock5 Proxy.

I have added the proxy address and port number in Internet Settings in Control Pannel.

But when I analyse through Wireshark the packets that we are being exchanged, I see that my machine is communicating ditrectly with the destination.

However, when I analyse the packet that happens when I use chrome or TOR, the exchange looks to be happening through the Sock5 Proxy server.

Follwing is my snippet that I use to make connection :

```
         xmlhttp.setProxy SXH_PROXY_SET_PRECONFIG
  xmlhttp.Open "GET", url, False

            xmlhttp.setrequestheader "Content-Type", "text/html"

           xmlhttp.setrequestheader "User-Agent", " Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0"

        xmlhttp.setrequestheader "Connection", " keep-alive"
        xmlhttp.setrequestheader "Cache-Control", "max-age=0"
        xmlhttp.setrequestheader "Accept-Language", "en-us,en;q=0.5"
        xmlhttp.setrequestheader "Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"

        xmlhttp.send
```

Though I am not sure whether I am using "SetProxy" correctly or not.

Please Help..

Comment: I have also tried setting default proxy using "proxycfg -u" but still all of the traffic from the VBA is reaching the destination directly rather than reaching via proxy server

Comment: Guys please help...i am so close to pulling off something spectacular....